# predict function in glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

What kind of object the predict function in glmnet returns ?
I can't access the values of predict.

```
x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
g4=sample(1:4,100,replace=TRUE)
fit3=glmnet(x,g4,family="multinomial")
res <-predict(fit3,newx=x[1:2,],type="response", s=0.01)

res
, , 1
             1         2         3         4
[1,] 0.3166811 0.1829920 0.3516546 0.1486724
[2,] 0.3413679 0.2532931 0.2466071 0.1587319

res[,1] #try to get the first column 
Error in res[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I want to access only the first column. What is the proper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in

```
str(res)
# num [1:2, 1:4, 1] 0.2507 0.2902 0.2291 0.0869 0.1128 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#  ..$ : NULL
    #  ..$ : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
#  ..$ : chr "1"
```

and

```
dim(res)
#[1] 2 4 1
```

`res` is a 3-dimensional `numeric` array which is also evident by your error message. You need the extra index. So, something like

```
res[, 1, ]
```

will work. See `?predict.glmnet` for more information.

**Edit**: The return type is 3-dimensional with a slice for each penalty parameter given. Consider for example the following.

```
res2 <- predict(fit3, newx = x[1:2,], type = "response", s = c(0.01, 0.02))
res2
#, , 1
# 
#             1          2         3         4
#[1,] 0.2506749 0.22905072 0.1127754 0.4074990
#[2,] 0.2901530 0.08685651 0.1769566 0.4460339
# 
#, , 2
#
#             1         2         3         4
#[1,] 0.2264911 0.2359210 0.1300334 0.4075546
#[2,] 0.2393564 0.1008442 0.2366757 0.4231237
```

Here each `res2[,,1]` corresponds to the first penalty and `res2[,,2]` to the second.

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. Is there any specific reason why it returns 3-dimensional numeric array? A simple 2-D array could have done this.

Comment: ?predict.glmnet says only "The object returned depends on type."

Comment: @d.putto Yes, I know. But there *is* some info in the details section and arguments section. It returns a 3-dimensional array since there is a slice for each penalty parameter. I'll edit my answer.